# Removing solid background from Android Material DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have a `DatePickerDialog` which looks like this

[image]

I have been trying to remove background from bottom buttons without success. So far I have tried to set `buttonStyle` `buttonBarStyle` in theme but it did not work out. My app theme is derived from `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` and I have following `datePickerStyle` in my `styles.xml`

```
    <style name="DatePickerDialogStyle" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

I am setting it in my `AppTheme` as follows

```
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DatePickerDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePickerDialogStyle</item>
```

How can I remove background from these buttons?

Comment: If you change those `colorPrimary` values in your styles, for the color blue for example, does it change the color of the background color of the buttons? Just trying to understand if the color change is taking effect.

Comment: yes it does change the color!

Answer (score 1):

You can programmaticaly set the `DatePickerDialog` values before showing it, like so:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this);
datePickerDialog.getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
datePickerDialog.getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

You can also set other properties, like textColor, dimensions, etc. Check [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog) for more info on this.

Comment: this crashes because getButton() returns `null` here

Comment: Oh, I thought you were also doing the `setButton()` before that. In this case, you can do the `setButton` with the configuration that you want and then call the `getButton().setBackgroundColor()`. Not the best example, but you can extract some info on how to use `setButton` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16583969/7671879).

Comment: Also, in order for the click functionality of the buttons to work, you have to set the listeners programatically aswell. Just check the different constructors of the `DatePickerDialog`, there's a case for adding the OnClickListener.

Comment: it still crashes after calling `setButton` on `DatePickerDialog`

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace of the crash?